# How do I take this docker image on github modify it, then upload it as a docker image to docker hub

Tags: docker, dockerfile

So [this](https://github.com/mattrayner/docker-lamp) is the image on GitHub that I wanted to push to my Docker Hub as an image.

I wanted to add a boostrap4 framework installation to the docker file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a dockerfile with the image you want as base image. Install bootstrap4 and build the image. Then you can push the new image to your docker hub.

Dockerfile might look  something like this -

```
FROM mattrayner/lamp:latest-1804

# Your commands to install bootstrap here

CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

`docker build -t my_new_lamp_image:my_tag .`

`docker tag my_new_lamp_image:my_tag <my_docker_hub_path>/my_new_lamp_image:my_tag`

`docker push <my_docker_hub_path>/my_new_lamp_image:my_tag`